# Parse business hours Time Slots and Week Days from JSON array with PHP

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, json

Can't figure out how to properly parse a JSON array with PHP.

In my script, I have a foreach statement that parses a local JSON file, extract data and insert it on the database.

Everything is ok except the parsing of the week and business hours.

This is what i've done:

```
$openingHours = $json_data['openingHours'];
```

every json file may return an array with different rows like in this output:

```
example 1: 
"openingHours" : [
"Su 09:00 - 23:59",
"Mo 00:00 - 23:59",
"Tu 00:00 - 13:00, 15:30 - 19:30",
"We 08:30 - 13:00, 15:30 - 19:30",
"Th 08:30 - 13:00, 15:30 - 19:30",
"Fr 08:30 - 13:00, 15:30 - 19:30",
"Sa 08:30 - 13:00, 15:30 - 19:30" ]

 exampe 2:
"openingHours" : [
"Mo 08:00 - 13:00, 16:00 - 20:00",
"Tu 08:00 - 13:00, 16:00 - 20:00",
"We 08:00 - 13:00, 16:00 - 20:00",
"Th 08:00 - 13:00, 16:00 - 20:00",
"Fr 08:00 - 13:00, 16:00 - 20:00",
"Sa 08:00 - 13:00, 16:00 - 20:00" ]

 example 3:
 "openingHours" : [
"Mo 08:00 - 13:00, 16:00 - 20:00",
"We 08:00 - 13:00, 16:00 - 20:00",
"Th 08:00 - 13:00, 16:00 - 20:00",
"Sa 08:00 - 13:00, 16:00 - 20:00" ]
```

As you can see, in the first json I have all 7 days, on the second example there are 6 days from Monday to Saturday, and in the third example there are 4 days Mo-We-Th-Sa

So I'm going to create a foreach statement to output the data;

```
foreach ($openingHours as $k_day=>$v_day) {

    $openHrs = $openingHours[$k_day];
    echo print_r($openHrs)."<br>"; 

}
```

it produce an output like this:

```
FILE 1:
Mo 08:30 - 12:30, 16:00 - 20:00
Tu 08:30 - 12:30, 16:00 - 20:00
We 08:30 - 12:30, 16:00 - 20:00
Th 16:00 - 20:00
Fr 08:30 - 12:30, 16:00 - 20:00
Sa 08:30 - 12:30, 16:00 - 20:00

FILE 2:
Su 09:00 - 23:59
Mo 00:00 - 23:59
Tu 00:00 - 13:00, 15:30 - 19:30
We 08:30 - 13:00, 15:30 - 19:30
Th 08:30 - 13:00, 15:30 - 19:30
Sa 08:30 - 13:00, 15:30 - 19:30

FILE N:
.....
```

At this point i need to create some rules to properly format and extract days and business hours from array.

First of all I have to declare days of the week that start from Sunday

```
0 - Su
1 - Mo
2 - Tu
3 - We
4 - Th
5 - Fr
6 - Sa
```

Then, check if there all week string (Su - Mo -Tu...) in array and if some day is missing, add them to the list in a correct position.

As in this example

```
"openingHours" : [
"Mo 08:00 - 13:00, 16:00 - 20:00",
"We 08:00 - 13:00",
"Th 08:00 - 13:00, 16:00 - 20:00",
"Sa 08:00 - 13:00, 16:00 - 20:00" ]
```

the days: Su - Tu - Fr, doesn't exist (it means that in these days the Shop is closed).

On "Wednesday" it's open only from 08:00 to 13:00, and the 3rd and 4th-time slots don't exist. It means that I need to insert 2-time slots. 
Obviously for closed days i need to insert the time slots too ("00:00 - 00:00, 00:00 - 00:00").

```
0 - <-- insert
1 - Mo
2 - <-- insert
3 - We --> add "00:00 - 00:00"
4 - Th
5 - <-- insert
6 - Sa
```

**Summing up,** 
all days rows and their slots must be populated with proper data.

At the last point, before pass the data to the database, I need the properly parameterize variables.

This is mine CREATE TABLE statement of the table where i want to put data:

```
CREATE TABLE `business_hours_temp` (
`id` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`place_id` INT(11) NOT NULL,
`day` INT(1) NOT NULL,
`open_1` TIME NOT NULL,
`close_1` TIME NOT NULL,
`open_2` TIME NOT NULL,
`close_2` TIME NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
INDEX `place_id` (`place_id`)
)
 COLLATE='utf8mb4_unicode_ci'
 ENGINE=InnoDB
 AUTO_INCREMENT=12;
```

and this is an INSERT INTO statement

```
$stmt_hours = $conn->prepare(
    'INSERT INTO business_hours_temp( place_id, day, open_1, close_1, open_2, close_2 )
     VALUES(:place_id, :field_id, :field_value)');
$stmt_hours->bindValue(':place_id', $place_id);
$stmt_hours->bindValue(':day', $day);
$stmt_hours->bindValue(':open_1', $open_1);
$stmt_hours->bindValue(':close_1', $close_1);
$stmt_hours->bindValue(':open_2', $open_2);
$stmt_hours->bindValue(':close_2', $close_2);
$stmt_hours->execute();
```

I need to get vals for `$day - $open_1 - $close_1 - $open_2 - $close_2`

Thank you guys for any help.

Comment: And the hours are always the same for any given json?

Comment: Hi mate, 
No - the hours slots are not the same. This is a list of local businesses, and they may have different time slots.

Comment: I would amend the examples to reflect that

Comment: Thanks. I know that it is a little bit complex problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanx Jimmix!
It Works!

I just make some little changes to catch the values for the variables i wanted.
The code has comments. Thnak you again.

```
foreach($resultFilledList as $result) {
    $line = '';
    $line .= $daysLut2[$result['dayNo']];
    $line .= ' ' . $result['open1'];
    $line .= ', ' . $result['open2'];

    $lineList[] = $line;

    //FOR STORING DATA IN DB
    //get DAY - INT
    $day = $daysLut2[$result['dayNo']];

    // SPLIT/EXPLODE Main slot 1 and 2
    // and get time_slot 1,2, 3 and 4
    // trim the EXPLODE and add ":00" for proper MySQL TIME type
    $main_slot_1 = $result['open1'];
    $main_slot_1_expl = explode('-',$main_slot_1,2);

    $main_slot_2 = $result['open2'];
    $main_slot_2_expl = explode('-',$main_slot_2,2);

    $time_slot_1 = trim($main_slot_1_expl[0], ' ').":00";
    $time_slot_2 = trim($main_slot_1_expl[1], ' ').":00";
    $time_slot_3 = trim($main_slot_2_expl[0], ' ').":00";
    $time_slot_4 = trim($main_slot_2_expl[1], ' ').":00";
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php

$openingHours1 = [
    "Su 09:00 - 23:59",
    "Mo 00:00 - 23:59",
    "Tu 00:00 - 13:00, 15:30 - 19:30",
    "We 08:30 - 13:00, 15:30 - 19:30",
    "Th 08:30 - 13:00, 15:30 - 19:30",
    "Fr 08:30 - 13:00, 15:30 - 19:30",
    "Sa 08:30 - 13:00, 15:30 - 19:30" ];


$openingHours3 = [
    "Mo 08:00 - 13:00, 16:00 - 20:00",
    "We 08:00 - 13:00, 16:00 - 20:00",
    "Th 08:00 - 13:00, 16:00 - 20:00",
    "Sa 08:00 - 13:00, 16:00 - 20:00" ];    


$openingHours2 = [
    "Mo 08:00 - 13:00, 16:00 - 20:00",
    "Tu 08:00 - 13:00, 16:00 - 20:00",
    "We 08:00 - 13:00, 16:00 - 20:00",
    "Th 08:00 - 13:00, 16:00 - 20:00",
    "Fr 08:00 - 13:00, 16:00 - 20:00",
    "Sa 08:00 - 13:00, 16:00 - 20:00" ];


function parse($openingHours)
{    
    $resultList = [];

    $daysLut = [
        'Su' => 0,
        'Mo' => 1,
        'Tu' => 2,
        'We' => 3,
        'Th' => 4,
        'Fr' => 5,
        'Sa' => 6,
    ];


    $counter = 0;
    $dayNoLut = [];

    foreach ($openingHours as $oppening) {
        $open1 = null;
        $open2 = null;

        $dayLetter = substr($oppening, 0, 2);
        $dayNo = $daysLut[$dayLetter];

        $open1 = substr($oppening, 3, 13);

        if(strlen($oppening) > 18) {
            $open2 = substr($oppening, 18);
        }

        if(empty($open2)) {
            $open2 = "00:00 - 00:00";
        }

        $result['dayNo'] = $dayNo;
        $result['open1'] = $open1;
        $result['open2'] = $open2;

        $dayNoLut[$dayNo] = $counter;

        $resultList[] = $result;
        $counter++;
    }

    $resultFilledList = [];
    $resultListCount = count($resultList);
    if($resultListCount < 7) {
        $result = [];
        $result['open1'] = "00:00 - 00:00";

        //remove this line if for a cloed day you want only one 00:00 - 00:00
        $result['open2'] = "00:00 - 00:00";

        for($i=0; $i<7; $i++) {
            $result['dayNo'] = $i;

            if(key_exists($i, $dayNoLut)) {
                $resultFilledList[$i] = $resultList[$dayNoLut[$i]];
            } else {
                $resultFilledList[$i] = $result;
            }
        }
    } else {
        $resultFilledList = $resultList;
    }

    return $resultFilledList;

}


$resultFilledList = parse($openingHours3);
print_r($resultFilledList);

$daysLut2 = [
    0 => 'Su',
    1 => 'Mo',
    2 => 'Tu',
    3 => 'We',
    4 => 'Th',
    5 => 'Fr',
    6 => 'Sa',
];


$lineList = [];
foreach($resultFilledList as $result) {
    $line = '';
    $line .= $daysLut2[$result['dayNo']];
    $line .= ' ' . $result['open1'];
    $line .= ', ' . $result['open2'];

    $lineList[] = $line;
}

print_r($lineList);

$lineList = [];
foreach($resultFilledList as $result) {
    $line = '';

    $line = $result['dayNo'];
    $line .= ' - ';

    $line .= $daysLut2[$result['dayNo']];
    $line .= ' ' . $result['open1'];
    $line .= ', ' . $result['open2'];

    $lineList[] = $line;
}

print_r($lineList);
```

gives output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [open1] => 00:00 - 00:00
            [open2] => 00:00 - 00:00
            [dayNo] => 0
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [dayNo] => 1
            [open1] => 08:00 - 13:00
            [open2] => 16:00 - 20:00
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [open1] => 00:00 - 00:00
            [open2] => 00:00 - 00:00
            [dayNo] => 2
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [dayNo] => 3
            [open1] => 08:00 - 13:00
            [open2] => 16:00 - 20:00
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [dayNo] => 4
            [open1] => 08:00 - 13:00
            [open2] => 16:00 - 20:00
        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [open1] => 00:00 - 00:00
            [open2] => 00:00 - 00:00
            [dayNo] => 5
        )

    [6] => Array
        (
            [dayNo] => 6
            [open1] => 08:00 - 13:00
            [open2] => 16:00 - 20:00
        )

)
Array
(
    [0] => Su 00:00 - 00:00, 00:00 - 00:00
    [1] => Mo 08:00 - 13:00, 16:00 - 20:00
    [2] => Tu 00:00 - 00:00, 00:00 - 00:00
    [3] => We 08:00 - 13:00, 16:00 - 20:00
    [4] => Th 08:00 - 13:00, 16:00 - 20:00
    [5] => Fr 00:00 - 00:00, 00:00 - 00:00
    [6] => Sa 08:00 - 13:00, 16:00 - 20:00
)
Array
(
    [0] => 0 - Su 00:00 - 00:00, 00:00 - 00:00
    [1] => 1 - Mo 08:00 - 13:00, 16:00 - 20:00
    [2] => 2 - Tu 00:00 - 00:00, 00:00 - 00:00
    [3] => 3 - We 08:00 - 13:00, 16:00 - 20:00
    [4] => 4 - Th 08:00 - 13:00, 16:00 - 20:00
    [5] => 5 - Fr 00:00 - 00:00, 00:00 - 00:00
    [6] => 6 - Sa 08:00 - 13:00, 16:00 - 20:00
)
```

just use

```
$resultFilledList = parse($openingHours3);
```

where `oppeningHours3` is an array. so if you have it in json use `$openingHours3 = json_decode($data, true);`,

and then

print it or iterate over it with foreach loop as I did in my code.

Comment: Thank you Jimmix, i'm going to check and will let you know if it works... thank you again, i really appreciate it.